# How to prevent custom dialog from blinking cursor on first EditText inside of it

Tags: android, dialog, android-edittext

I am creating a custom `Dialog` window but my problem is when the dialog first launches it automatically begins flashing the cursor on the FIRST `EditText` in the `LinearLayout` that defines the structure of the dialog. The keyboard does not appear, but the first `EditText` always has this blinking cursor on it.

I attempted to use the `RequestFocus()` function on a `TextView` within the dialog that cannot be edited, but the blinking cursor remains on the first `EditText` in the dialog.

If anyone has any advice or solutions to solving this problem, that would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use either XML attribute or Java function-

**xml:**

```
android:cursorVisible="false"
```

**Java function:**

```
setCursorVisible(false)
```

Comment: This isn't exactly the most elegant way, but if I just call setCursorVisible accordingly, it should work fine. Many thanks!

Comment: Glad it helped :)!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to stop `EditText` from gaining focus at startup, add these two lines to parent layout (e.g. `LinearLayout`).

```
android:focusable="true" 
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```